# is there any possibility to run the exe with wix during installation?

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am very new to wix. Is there any possibility to run a exe file with the help of wix during the installation.

So for i have done and i dont know now to install a exe file. please help...

```
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject1" />
        </Directory>
     </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="ProgramFilesFolder">
         <Component Id="ProductComponent">
          <File Id="PLGSMPL" Source="$(var.PLGSMPL.TargetPath)"/>
          <RemoveFile Id="plug_in" Name="PLGSMPL.dll" On="uninstall" />
         </Component> 
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to run an EXE during installation is using the [Quiet Execution Custom Action - WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html).

However, I caution on doing this as whatever the EXE does is unknown to MSI. It can't be monitored for repair, it can't be rolled back, it can't be observed or transformed using ORCA and can introduce fragility into your installer.